# How can I get the wallet address for a given herotag?

Tags: blockchain, multiversx

If I want to get the herotag for a given wallet address, I can simply call the following endpoint:

https://api.elrond.com/accounts/erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g

and I get:

```
{
   "address":"erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g",
   "nonce":4,
   "balance":"0",
   "rootHash":"QU6o17Qw4KUPnpU6e6QbEuvKUTA8SPy52QFseslWsG4=",
   "txCount":4,
   "username":"event.elrond",
   "shard":1
}
```

where I see the `username`.

But now I'd like to obtain the wallet address for a given herotag.

Is there any API endpoint for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using API

```
https://api.elrond.com/usernames/<herotag>
```

E.g.:

https://api.elrond.com/usernames/event

redirects to

https://api.elrond.com/accounts/erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g

and returns

```
{
  "address": "erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g",
  "nonce": 7,
  "balance": "254914476000000000",
  "rootHash": "QU6o17Qw4KUPnpU6e6QbEuvKUTA8SPy52QFseslWsG4=",
  "txCount": 9,
  "scrCount": 12,
  "username": "event.elrond",
  "shard": 1,
  "developerReward": "0"
}
```

#### Using `erdpy`

```
erdpy dns resolve <herotag>.elrond --proxy=https://gateway.elrond.com
```

where `<herotag>` should be replaced by its value.

E.g.:

```
erdpy dns resolve event.elrond --proxy=https://gateway.elrond.com
```

outputs

```
erd1hw78kxyj353x52hmmq6dzxgexynwt4m29q2uvpq6xdm90z3halvsl7cn6g
```

**Details**:

```
$ erdpy --version
erdpy 1.0.12
```